# System.Linq.IQueryable does not contain a definition for 'Where'

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

Very odd situation here. For some reason I can't call 'Where', or any other functions, on my IQueryable object.

Here's what I have:

```
public IQueryable<Employee> Employees
{
    get { return _entities.Employees.AsQueryable(); }
}


public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new HomeViewModel
        {
            Employees = Employees.Where(e => e.Active == true)
        });
}
```

But Intellisense doesn't pick up the Where function, and I get a Build Error that says:

> 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

But I can call `.Where` like this and it works:

```
public IQueryable<Employee> Employees
{
    get { return _entities.Employees.AsQueryable().Where(e => e.Active == true); }
}
```

I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Just to make sure, do you have using System.Linq included at the top?

Comment: Are both those code snippets in the same file? Do you have `using System.Linq;` at the top?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need to add a `using System.Linq;` ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx)) <del>statement</del> directive in the file where it isn't working.  All of the extension methods for IEnumerable/IQueryable are defined in the [Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) and [Queryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.aspx) classes, respectively.

In order to use extension methods, the class defining the method must be in scope.  My guess is that your second code snippet comes from another file where you do have the using statement.

Comment: Tiny nitpick: `using System.Linq;` is a directive, not a statement :)

Comment: Edited accordingly Jon :) NP Steven.

Comment: Using System.LINQ is at the top of mine and I have several other selects in the function which do not throw this error>

Comment: @user1161391 then the object you are trying to call it on does not implement IQueryable or IEnumerable.