# ASP.NET MVC How to use DbSet with multiple conditions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext, dbset

I have a Person model in ASP.NET MVC, and I'm working with DbContext, and I have
a DbSet to this model.
I have first name, last name, nick name fields.
I want to know how can I select persons with DbSet with *several* conditions.

If it was SQL, I want to do this:

```
select * from persons where firstName like '%something%' and
lastName like '%something%' and
nickName like '%something%';
```

How can I do it with DbSet?
I have the next code:

```
    public ActionResult SearchPerson([Bind(Include = "Id,FirstName,LastName,NickName")] Person person)
    {
        DbSet<Person> result = db.Persons;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(person.FirstName))
        {
            result.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(person.FirstName));
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(person.LastName))
        {
            result.Where(x => x.LastName.Contains(person.LastName));
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(person.NickName))
        {
            result.Where(x => x.NickName.Contains(person.NickName));
        }

        return View(result.ToList());
    }
```

It seems the is no AND clause or any WHERE clause between
the conditions, and result.ToList() gives me ALL the results from the DB.
Any help?

Comment: `result = result.Where(...)` everywhere.

Comment: not working! I get the next exception: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery to type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet

Comment: Change your declaration to `IQueryable<Person> result = db.Persons`.

Comment: IQueryable does not contains 'Where' method. any other suggestions?

Comment: Try searching. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489848/system-linq-iqueryable-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-where

Comment: Found there the solution!! thanks!